# Can a Firebase onCall function perform retries?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I noticed that onCall functions do not have a context.eventId like triggers do. Is there a need to make these onCall functions idempotent or will they never perform retries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calls to `onCall` functions are not automatically retried. It's up to your application's client-side and server-side code, to agree on a retry strategy.