# How to make callable google cloud function idempotent

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin, idempotent

I have a google cloud function that sends notifications to a firebase topic.
The function was working fine till suddenly, it start to send more than one notification 2 or 3 at the same time. After contacting the Firebase support team, they told may I should **make the function Idempotent**, but I don't know how, since it's a callable function.
for more details, [this is a reference question containing more detail about the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72818169/google-cloud-function-sends-duplicate-notification).
below is the function's code.

- **UPDATE 2**

**it was a bug in the admin sdk and they resolved it in the last release.**

**UPDATE**

*the function is already idempotent* because it is an event driven function
the link above contains the functions log as prof it runs only once.
after 2 month on go and back it appears **the problem with firebase admin sdk**
the function code `getMessaging().sendToTopic()` has retry 4 times and the origin request so its 5 times by default before throwing error and terminate the function. So the reason of duplicate notification  is that the admin sdk from time to time cant reach the FCM server for some reason.it try to send notification to all subs but in half way or before send all notification it get error so it retry again from the beginning so some users receives one notification and some get 2, 3,4.
And Now the question is how to prevent these default retries or how to make the retry continue from where it get the error. probably Ill ask a separated question.
For now I did a naive solution by prevent the duplicate notification from the receiver( mobile client). if it get more than one notification has same content within a minute show only one.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

// The Firebase Admin SDK to access Firestore.
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const {getMessaging} = require("firebase-admin/messaging");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://mylinktodatabase.firebaseio.com",
});

exports.callNotification = functions.https.onCall( (data) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const indicator = data.indicator;
  const mTitle = data.title;
  const mBody = data.body;
  // topic to send to
  const topic = "mytopic";
  const options = {
    "priority": "high",
    "timeToLive": 3600,
  };
  let message;
  if (indicator != null ) {
    message = {
      data: {
        ind: indicator,
      },
    };
  } else {
    message = {
      data: {
        title: mTitle,
        body: mBody,
      },
    };
  }

  // Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
  return getMessaging().sendToTopic(topic, message, options)
      .then(() => {
        if (indicator != null ) {
          console.log("Successfully sent message");
          return {
            result: "Successfully sent message", status: 200};
        } else {
          console.log("Successfully sent custom");
          return {
            result: "Successfully sent custom", status: 200};
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (indicator != null ) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
          return {result: `Error sending message: ${error}`, status: 500};
        } else {
          console.log("Error sending custom:", error);
          return {result: `Error sending custom: ${error}`, status: 500};
        }
      });
});
```

Comment: Did you had a canche to check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72917812/13171940)?

Comment: Sorry for being late, I was investigating other apps/ bugs.

Answer (score 0):

In this blog *[Cloud Functions pro tips: Building idempotent functions](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-functions-pro-tips-building-idempotent-functions)*,  shows how to do a function idempotent using two approaches:

> **Use your event IDs**
>
> One way to fix this is to use the event ID, a number that uniquely identifies an event that triggers a background function, and— this is important—remains unchanged across function retries for the same event.
> [image: 4.png][image]
>
> To use an event ID to solve the duplicates problem, the first thing is to extract it from the event context that is accessed through  [function parameters](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/background#function_parameters). Then, we utilize the event ID as a document ID and write the document contents to Cloud Firestore. This way, a retried function execution doesn’t create a new document, just overrides the existing one with the same content. Similarly, some external APIs (e.g.,  [Stripe](https://stripe.com/blog/idempotency)) accept an idempotency key to prevent data or work duplication. If you depend on such an API, simply provide the event ID as your idempotency key.
>
> **A new lease on retries**
>
> While this approach eliminates the vast majority of duplicated calls on function retries, there’s a small chance that two retried executions running in parallel could execute the critical section more than once. To all but eliminate this problem, you can use a lease mechanism, which lets you exclusively execute the non-idempotent section of the function for a specific amount of time. In this example, the first execution attempt gets the lease, but the second attempt is rejected because the lease is still held by the first attempt. Finally, a third attempt after the first one fails re-takes the lease and successfully processes the event.
>
> [image: 5.png][image]
>
> To apply this approach to your code, simply run a Cloud Firestore transaction before you send your email, checking to see if the event has been handled, but also storing the time until which the current execution attempt has exclusive rights to sending the email. Other concurrent execution attempts will be rejected until the lease expires, eliminating all duplicates for all intents and purposes.

Also, as stated in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416648/can-a-firebase-oncall-function-perform-retries):

> Q: Is there a need to make these onCall functions idempotent or will they never perform retries?
>
> A: Calls to `onCall` functions are not automatically retried. It's up to your application's client-side and server-side code, to agree on a retry strategy.

See also:

- [Retrying Event-Driven Functions - Best practices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries#best_practices)

Comment: It's a convenient answer, but there are many problems that don't fit my case.
- The function doesn't retry either from the server or client sides. (checked )
- A friend of mine has a PHP server with the same issue ( redundant notification).
- the problem with Firebase, now investigating with the support team.
* one way to make an event-driven function (callable) idempotent is by sending a counter or id to the function and checking in the function code with this anchor (counter or id)// I didn't test it yet, but I'll update my comment when I test it.

Comment: @MostafaOnaizan did you had a chance to do some tests using counter/id?

Comment: yes I did, and I'll share the code later on, but the problem within the admin sdk. Firebase asked me to simulate the whole situation for them so they can work on it. But that would be too much for me

Comment: I updated the question, you may take a look at it