# How to push notifications based on changes?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, push-notification

I am trying to make an app which listens to changes of the Internet API even if the app is closed, and sends push notification to the user who set up some value matching conditions with the value from the API. I am new to push motifications and I am not sure if is that possible with natvie notifications system or I have to use some 3rd parties like Firebase Messaging.

Comment: This is something you should code in a server/service. It can then send a push notification when required

Comment: Can you recommend me this type of server or service?

Comment: You can look at Azure or AWS or Google Cloud. They all have similar capabilities and free tiers.

Comment: Will Firebase be okay for that?

Comment: Yes. You could use a cloud function or cloud run from firebase plus Firestore to store your push tokens and either FCM or just send push directly using APNS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250162/discussion-between-green8-and-paulw11).

Comment: check this, this code is working fine.
its a  google cloud function and its almost free.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72913107/how-to-make-callable-google-cloud-function-idempotent

Comment: [this](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) repo is an excellent resource